# How do u display this image and .titleclass .subtitleclass .description when a click the image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

```
<?php while($galleryvalidate = mysqli_fetch_array($getresultgallery)){ ?>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 mb-4 mb-lg-0" id="imageidback">
       
        <img
          data-id ="<?php echo $galleryvalidate['publishid']; ?>"
          src="<?php echo $folder.$galleryvalidate['publishimage']; ?>"
          class="w-100 shadow-1-strong rounded mb-4"
          alt=""
          style="cursor:pointer;"
          
          name="imagequery"
      
        />
        <input type="hidden" class="titleclass" name="titlename" id="titlenameid" value="<?php echo $galleryvalidate['title'] ?>">
        <input type="hidden" class="subtitleclass" name="subtitlename" id="subtitlenameid" value="<?php echo $galleryvalidate['subtitle'] ?>">
        <input type="hidden" class="descriptionclass" name="descriptionname" id="descriptionnameid" value="<?php echo $galleryvalidate['description'] ?>">
      
       
      </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

NOTE: the image is in loop function in php script.Please help its been 3 days im thinking about this and still finding a source :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to convert the hidden text elements into editable text elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img.imgquery').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('div').find('input[type=hidden]').attr('type', 'text');
  })
})
```

```css
div input {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 mb-4 mb-lg-0" id="imageidback">

  <img data-id="<?php echo $galleryvalidate['publishid']; ?>" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="w-100 shadow-1-strong rounded mb-4 imgquery" alt="" style="cursor:pointer;" name="imagequery" />

  <input type="hidden" class="titleclass" name="titlename" id="titlenameid" value="<?php echo $galleryvalidate['title'] ?>">
  <input type="hidden" class="subtitleclass" name="subtitlename" id="subtitlenameid" value="<?php echo $galleryvalidate['subtitle'] ?>">
  <input type="hidden" class="descriptionclass" name="descriptionname" id="descriptionnameid" value="<?php echo $galleryvalidate['description'] ?>">


</div>
```